# Hibernate component

Tags: jpa, hibernate-mapping

I need to migrate some hibernate hbm files to JPA/Hibernate annotations.
The existing relationship is as follows -

1. The parent class has an ID
2. The component class also has an ID

The 2 identifiers refer to different sequences.

I have used `@Embedded` and `@AttributeOverride` in the parent class, and `@Embeddable` in the component class.

Both the classes are entities.

The exception i get when i try to save a parent class object is -

> org.hibernate.MappingException: component property not found: id

I suppose the exception is because i have 2 identifiers defined.

Any suggestions/workarounds on this will help greatly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't make something an `@Entity` *and* `@Embeddable` at the same time, that makes no sense. You have to make it one or the other.

If both have an ID, and both are entities, then the Hibernate/JPA component/embeddable model doesn't apply.

Comment: It **does** make sense. I have a class, that I reuse in different circumstances. Normally, this class is mapped as an entity. But when I reuse it, it is mapped as a component (aka embedded). This is totally valid, in my XML-mapping, where the mapping-data is not bound to the classes. But I found no way to realize this with annotations :/ I tried `@AttributeOverrides`, but it does not help...

Comment: If someone stumbles on this question as I did, you might want to consider creating a one to one, one to many, ... relationship using the given ``javax.persistance`` annotations like ``@OneToOne``. See also: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro001.htm

Comment: @Lucas it is not the same thing. A one to one will live in a separate table which for performance reasons you might not desire to. I am with Kai, you might not want to duplicate your class just so you can avoid using \@Entity. Skaffman is not correct here. Advocating redundancy is not a better way.